# QML XmlListModel recursive(?) query

Tags: xml, xpath, qml

I have an xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <plcValue>dgIconXY11.value</plcValue>
    <state>Grip1IsClamped.png</state>
    <state>Grip1IsMove.png</state>
</root>
```

I query this xml with this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.12

XmlListModel {
    id: xmlIconModel

    property int stateNr

    source: "listViewIcons.xml"
    query: "/root"

    XmlRole {
        name: "sPLCval"
        query: "plcValue/string()"
    }

    XmlRole {
        name: "sState"
        query: "state[" + stateNr + "]/string()"
    }
}
```

And then use it with this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    id: iconGridBg

    property int currIndex

    width: 36
    height: 36

    color: "black"

    Image {
        id: iconListImg
        height: 36
        width: 36

        source: sState
    }
}
```

QUESTION:
I'd like to use the plcValue string and get it's value from code and with that value I'd like to get the nth status value of the same branch.

So I have a `dgIconXY11.value` somewhere in my code. It's value will be an int and based on that int if it's eg.: 1 I'd like to get the 1st state and if it's 2 the 2nd state.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not succesful with the recursive query.
The workaround is to have two (or more) `XmlListModel`s. First get the information for the 2nd query like `sPLCval` in my case.